# QNAP: ACL does not work over NFS

Tags: nfs, access-control-list, qnap

Having difficulties making Linux ACL (getfacl/setfacl) work with NFS shares. We are using Ubuntu clients and QNAP storage as server.

At the moment only root user on Ubuntu has read/write access. Normal user (like www-data) gets permission denied when trying to write something.

We created the same users (www-data, ubuntu) on QNAP, set the same UIDs and GUIDs by editing `/etc/passwd` `/etc/group` but it does not help. Weird.

Our setup is the following:

QNAP:

1.) Feature "Enable Advanced Folder Permissions" is checked

2.) `/etc/exports` is auto-generated on qnap and is the following

```
"/share/MD0_DATA/Public" *(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)
"/share/MD0_DATA/XXX" X.X.X.X(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)  X.X.X.X(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)  X.X.X.X(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)  X.X.X.X(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)
```

basically it sets "rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure" for all the exported partitions

Client (Ubuntu):

1.) `/etc/fstab`

```
X.X.X.X:/XXX /external nfs acl,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
```

2.) `getfacl /external` shows:

```
# file: external
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:ubuntu:rwx
user:nobody:---
group::---
group:users:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:ubuntu:rwx
default:user:nobody:---
default:group::rwx
default:group:users:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

The share is visible, but only root has write access. All others (like ubuntu, www-data) users have only read access. We would like to use ACL, at the moment we can only set RWX to POSIX 'others' which is not secure at all.

Comment: you should use nfs4_getfacl/setfacl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that ACLs do NOT work over NFS, especially V3 NFS.  However, I understand that there are some type of ACLs available in v4 NFS.  But I don't think that Linux ACLs work with NFS v4.....

Comment: mdpc, you are right concerning NFS4. The storage device we use QNAP TS-869U is rather new, but it supports only NFSv3. So it means we cannot use ACLs with it. Only good option i see is to use POSIX or give everybody full access.